# How to pass a parameter to docker with kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm starting a container using kubernetes and I have to send a -v parameter to docker. I'm searching for it about 3 hours and no success.
Here you can see my run command:

`kubectl run api --image=${API_IMAGE} --port=${PORT_SERVICE} --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1","spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [{"name": "api","image": "'${API_IMAGE}'","env": [{"name": "listen","value": "0.0.0.0"},{"name": "etcdAddr","value": "'${ETCD_ADDR}'"}]}]}}}}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Volumes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/volumes.md) construct, which is quite well explained in the docs and used in a number of examples.

If you want to use a host directory, use the `hostPath` volume type. There's an example of using it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/38aeddec8f9bdf2e1f25a5048c1b84a95dff7eac/examples/vitess/vtctld-controller.yaml).

Comment: I don't think `kubectl run` has good support for volumes, sadly.  I think OP will have to thunk down to YAML directly.

Comment: Yes, It works. I put `"volumeMounts": [{"name": "api", "mountPath": "/api"}]` in container definition and `"volumes":[{"name":"api","hostPath":{"path":"/api"}}]`